# Framework for integrating Django and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, framework, django

I am looking for a framework or another path for integrating Django and JavaScript. It seems that two popular framework are Backbone.js and AngularJS. Another path is to use coffeeScript. However I am not able by myself to guess which of them is more "natural". Furthermore, there must be others. I am particularly interested in something that allows:

1) easy integration

2) fast learning curve

3) JavaScript code minimization

4) rapid rest api development

5) large community

A) Are there clear advantages of any of them?

B) As I discovery (I am not sure if I am right) that backbone is based on a MVC paradigm and AngularJS is based on MVT paradigm like Django. Does this suggests that the later is more suitable for the task here or it does not imply anything?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Ext JS](http://sencha.com) or [jQuery](https://jquery.org/) to create AJAX requests to a [REST API](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) back end using [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). In that case, the only task Django would have is to read and write data to a database.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend React.js, as it is the most popular front-end framework out there nowadays. Great documentation and resources, like YouTube tutorials, due to the fact that it has a huge community, it was created and it is maintained by **Facebook** and last but not least it is on the trend!

> There are also great packages for React to use out there!